# My server intermittently won't serve pages to Safari 4... Need help!

Tags: apache, safari, ubuntu-8.04

I just upgraded my browser to Safari 4 and find that our website is having some major issues specific to that browser version.  As I click through pages on our site it takes one or two clicks before the browser window simply goes blank.  When the window goes blank, there is no source to view and no matter how many times I try to reload or if I try to load other pages of the site, I still get the blank window.  It's as if the server takes the request and simply returns a blank page.

If I wait over 15 seconds and then hit refresh again, the page loads fine.  Not sure why it starts working again...  Maybe a cache issue???

It's a PHP site and I've tried turning on error_reporting(E_ALL);, but that doesn't give any information.  I also tried putting an echo statement at the very beginning of the index.php file and verified that the page still goes blank without echoing that statement, so I'm thinking the problem is not php code specific.  The Apache error log does not show any issues.  I have the same site on my local development server and it doesn't have the problem.

Safari 4 is the only browser that shows this problem.  Does anyone have any ideas how to debug/fix this?

My webserver is ubuntu Hardy running Apache 2 an Mysql 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an nginx load balancer in front of the apache server and I just figured out that Safari 4 requires the nginx keepalive_timeout setting to be 0.  Took all day to figure that one out...

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue with Safari 4 on my site  but found that when reloading pages that return blanks, the request never even makes it to the server. No entry shows up in Apache's logs.

The keepalive setting for your LB sounds like a direction I could sniff in. Not sure what leeway I will have though, being on shared hosting.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a safari bug. We experience it too, and I have read other reports.

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2064488&start=0&tstart=0